how to wait until the function is complete in kotlin?
I have the function download URL and I want the main program to wait until I have a suitable URL and I can put it in the object:
    fun uploadImage(userName: String, uri: Uri): String
    {
        uploadImageProcess(userName , uri)
        return downloadUri
    }
     private fun uploadImageProcess(userName: String, uri: Uri){
        val ref = createReference(userName)
        Log.d("uploadImageFUNCTION", "Reference: $ref")
        val uploadTask = ref.putFile(uri)
        val urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                task.exception?.let {
                    Log.d("uploadImageFUNCTION", "task upload .exception: $task.exception")
                    throw it
                }
            }
            ref.downloadUrl
        }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("uploadImageFUNCTION", "task downloadUrl : ${task.result}")
                downloadUri = task.result.toString()
            } else {
                Log.d("uploadImageFUNCTION", "task downloadUrl .exception: $task.exception")
            }
        }

    }

I'm trying an async but no luck.

update: i fix the problem by using a call back when the download is complete a call back is update the url

The StorageReference#putFile(android.net.Uri) function returns an object of type UploadTask. As you can see in the docs, the UploadTask class is a subclass of the Task class. This means that you have two options to read the result of the operation of uploading the file. You either attach a OnCompleteListener as mentioned in the official documentation of getting the download URL or you can use Kotlin Coroutines and call await().
In both situations, you need to wait for the operation to complete. IMHO, the second approach is more recommended and easy to implement.

Hey Yam. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

thank you but i fix it myself by using a call back :)

Your question was "How to wait until the function is complete in Kotlin?". So I provided two ways in which you can wait for the operation to complete. Please also note the callbacks are some kind of old. But it's up to you to decide which solution fits best your needs.

Use coroutine like this
suspend fun uploadImageFile(): String {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val deferredResult = async {               
            uploadImage()
        }
        deferredResult.await()
    }
}


This async/await doesn't do anything. It can be just uploadImage(), directly in the withContext.

I fixed the problem with the help of a callback that will be activated as soon as the function ends and I won't have to do an await operation

Please provide details on your solution.
